# How to safely exit EXCEL if macro throws error from calling VBS

Tags: vba, vbscript

my VBS:

```
Dim WshShell, strCurDir
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strCurDir = WshShell.CurrentDirectory
Set objworkBook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(strCurDir & "\MasterSheetFetchJob.xlsm")
objworkBook.Fullflow
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close
objExcel.Application.Quit
WScript.Quit
```

Fullflow:

```
Sub Fullflow()
    Dim Host
    Set Host = CreateObject("BZWhll.WhllObj")
    Retval = Host.Connect("A")
    If (Retval) Then
        'Host.MsgBox "Error connecting to session A!", 48
    End If
    Host.ReadScreen localorvpn, 28, 2, 2
    'Enter Command in the TPXA or L TPX based on the connection Type
    If localorvpn = "PLEASE ENTER 'Command' TO LOGON" Then
        Host.WriteScreen "tpx", 3, 4
    Else
        Host.ReadScreen vpn, 13, 17, 5
        If vpn = "L application" Then
            Host.WriteScreen "L TPX", 24, 7
        Else
           'MsgBox ("Already logged in")
           Exit Function
        End If
    End If
    Host.SendKey "<ENTER>"
    'Waitfor UserId Text to appear in Login screen
    WaitForScreen "Userid", 11, 5
    Host.SendKey Username
    Host.SendKey "<TAB>"
    Host.SendKey mfp
    Host.WaitReady 10, 1000
    Host.SendKey "<ENTER>"
    WaitForScreen "MSGID", 1, 2
    Host.SendKey "<ENTER>"
    'TPXMenu....
    WaitForScreen "Sessid", 6, 6
End Sub
```

It is properly working when all good.. but during execution if host has some issue.. it stopped the execution thats fine.. but if we open excel it is shwoing it is ready only and not opening.. if we run again without killing excel.. workbook is getting corrupted and not usable..

so everytime we are killing excel before it starts the execution.. but problem is if we have some other not saved workbook also getting closed.. Is this the only to handle this error?

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

1. I would firstly call the `FullFlow` `Sub` (in the script code) in a different way:
   I would change

   `objworkBook.Fullflow`

with

```
objExcel.Application.Run "'" & strCurDir & "\MasterSheetFetchJob.xlsm" & "'!Fullflow"
```

2. Then, isn't it any other possibility to avoid sending keys to the 'Host' application? I mean, using API (FindWindow, FindWindowEx and SendMessage). Using Spy++ to see the window child three and find an appropriate way to determine the controls handlers... I do not use this application. Otherwise, I could help with some specific code...
3. Just from curiosity: why do you use Excel to run that function which does not return anything on a sheet (from what I could see) and not write the function directly in VBScript? It will not be much different, I think... Except the case when you need APIs and VBScript has a problem with this aspect.

Comment: It is mainframe automation using Rocket Bluezone. it supports macro and vbs only

Comment: if we call this using Run it wont lock Excel?

Comment: @ChanGan: If supports VBS, why do you involve Excel, too? Then, I cannot be sure that no error lock will be produced, but it is a more appropriate way of calling a sub from a workbook, using Excel automation...

Comment: initial plan to have vbs only.. but for vbs every time when i code changes,  i will get bit9 block to unlock that.. so i eliminated that

Comment: @ChanGan: What about the API approach, in order to avoid `Sendkey`, which may be a source of errors...

Comment: all the methods are using api method only https://www3.rocketsoftware.com/bluezone/help/v62/en/bzsh/default.htm

Comment: @ChanGan: Now, why using VBScript instead of only Excel VBA?

Comment: Do you have `BlueZone Plus VBA` installed?

Comment: @ChanGan: So, why are you loosing time with VBScript and Excel? It looks that the application has its own VBE. Read the documentation and start a different approach...